# Filter on "dataTables" when there are multiple tables on the same page (using @foreach in Laravel blade)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

Good morning. I need help, I have several  of dataTables inside a @foreach in a Laravel template, and the filters don't work. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
@foreach($tariffs as $tf)
    <table id="1-1-{{ $tf->id }}" 
        data-filter-control="true" style="vertical-align:middle;" data-toggle="table"
        data-locale="es-ES" data-page-list="[10, 20, 30]" data-page-size="10"
        data-buttons-class="xs btn-light" data-pagination="true"
        data-show-pagination-switch="true" class="table-borderless terminales_table">

        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach($new_tariffs as $nwt)
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

[image]

Can you help me pls? thanks